Running a Qt app from a docker on a remote machine
I have a Docker container in which I've set up a Qt dev-based environment.
This docker is located on my Ubuntu Linux machine, using Wayland.
I can run the container this way:
docker run --rm -ti -e QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland \
                    -e XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR \
                    -e WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0 \
                    -v $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/$WAYLAND_DISPLAY:$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/$WAYLAND_DISPLAY  \ 
                    --user=$(id -u):$(id -g) myqt5container 

And that works fine, I can launch qtcreator displayed in my Ubuntu session. Fine.
Question:
Could something similar be achieved if the docker container is located on a remote Linux machine (in a LAN)? Could it work?
Looks like something with X11 and ssh would be possible...but what about Wayland?
